# LCOV branch coverage not dumping data

Tags: gcov, lcov

I am trying to generate code coverage data from gcda using lcov.Following is the command I am using:

lcov -c --rc lcov_branch_coverage=1 -d /path -o try_main.info
But this is not dumping any data.

Following is the process seen:

/usr/bin/perl -w /usr/bin/geninfo /path --output-filename try_main.info --rc lcov_branch_coverage=1

But info file does not contain any data.
When I use gcov for branch data it dumps data very soon.Is lcov slow or any issue with my command?Any pre-requisite while compiling code for gcov branch coverage?

My LCOV version is:

lcov: LCOV version 1.10

Comment: Try posting the console output of the lcov command.  
You can also try out the latest code from their github page.

Comment: Its  not displaying any output it keeps running as shown by the process.

Comment: Have you compiled the code with --coverage compiler and the linker flag?  
Can you just try the gcov command with the generated *.gcno/*.gcda files and see if the gcov is working fine.  
For reference you can look [here](https://embeddedinn.wordpress.com/tutorials/test-coverage-analysis-with-gcov/) for more information.

Comment: With gcov its working fine its dumping branch data but when i use lcov command its not.

Comment: Can you try out the latest release from **lcov** github project page: [https://github.com/linux-test-project/lcov](https://github.com/linux-test-project/lcov)?

Comment: With the latest release of lcov the default branch coverage is not included in the coverage report. You can try these with lcov to dump branch coverage report:  

    $ lcov -rc lcov_branch_coverage=1 ...

or edit the ~/.lcovrc file containing:  

    # enable lcov branch report
    lcov_branch_coverage = 1
    # enable genhtml branch report
   genhtml_branch_coverage = 1